# Cannot get table field from belongsToMany relationship laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables DealerProduct and DealerProductPayments
dealer_products with id and dealer_id columns and dealer_products_payments table with id and dealer_products_id columns

and i have DealerProductPayment model with belongs to relationship

```
public function dealerproduct() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('DealerProduct','dealer_product_payments','dealer_product_id','id');
    }
```

im trying to get the dealer_id from belongsToMany relationship

```
$dealerProductPayment = DealerProductPayment::all();
        foreach ($dealerProductPayment as $payment) {
            echo $payment->dealerproduct->dealer_id;
        }
```

but its not working, can someone please helpme on this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `$payment->dealerproduct` will be a collection, because you stated the relationship to be `belongsToMany`. In a sense, one payment belongs to more than one products, hence, you will get a list of products when you do `$payment->dealerproduct`.

```
foreach ($dealerProductPayment as $payment) {
    foreach ($payment->dealerproduct as $dealerproduct) {
        echo $dealerproduct->dealer_id;
    }
}
```